# LVM 4,55 TiB Volume Group. I only can create a 2.70TiB logical volume

Tags: debian, configuration, lvm, disk-usage, limit

I create a Volume Group with 3 disks, 2 of 931g, and 1 of 2.73t. It seems like works propertly.

```
  sudo pvs
  PV         VG  Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree  
  /dev/sdb   nxt lvm2 a--  931.51g 931.51g
  /dev/sdc   nxt lvm2 a--  931.48g 931.48g
  /dev/sdd   nxt lvm2 a--   <2.73t  <2.73t
```

And when I run vgs and vgdisplay:

```
sudo vgs
 VG  #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree 
  nxt   3   0   0 wz--n- <4.55t <4.55t

sudo vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               nxt
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        3
  Metadata Sequence No  3
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                0
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                3
  Act PV                3
  VG Size               <4.55 TiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              1192314
  Alloc PE / Size       0 / 0   
  Free  PE / Size       1192314 / <4.55 TiB
  VG UUID               b9Gp5L-CBFr-wOAY-JAnw-kFWi-7vkL-Iidc5
```

I get that I had 1192314 of Free PE space, so i want to create an logical volume with that size.
So I run the command to generate it:

```
sudo lvcreate -i3 -I4 -l1192314 -n data nxt
  Insufficient suitable allocatable extents for logical volume data: 476937 more required
```

When I use the command by percent, create a LV with only 2,5TiB. Exists some limits to use LVM? O i need to change some config od the Volume Group?

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 2):

Two of your PVs are 931 GiB. The third one is 2.7 TiB.

A striped LV has to allocate the same space on all its PVs. In your case this means the LV's max size is 3*931 GiB, or roughly 2.7 TiB.

For more information about LVM allocation, see the [LVM (8) manpages](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lvm.8.html#ALLOCATION)

Answer (score 0):

LVM is like [RAID-0](https://searchstorage.techtarget.com/definition/RAID-0-disk-striping) by default. I don't see any reason to specify `-i` and `-I` in your `lvcreate` command, while sacrificing disk space. You could run the command without any special options and utilise all the disk space available. If you want to use all 4.5TB across three disks (data will be spread across all three disks as in RAID-0):

```
sudo lvcreate -L +4.50TB -n data nxt
```

(You cannot claim all 4.55TB but you can get at least 4.5TB or less)